# NextUI <Navbar> component is not sticking to the top

Tags: reactjs, next.js, components, styled-components, nextui

I am helping someone who has never used React, Next, or Tailwinds refactor to make their project design more responsive.

They had used NextUI components in some places, so when making edits to the navbar, I decided to refactor it so that it utilizes the [NextUI Navbar component](https://nextui.org/docs/components/navbar).

I have never used NextUI for components but have used other similar CSS frameworks for components, so I'm familiar with how they generally work. However, the component doesn't seem to be sticking to the top of the page even though the default value for the 'position' prop is 'sticky'.

#### Navbar Component code minus some fat

```
import Navbutton from "./Navbutton";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import ProfilePicture from "./ProfilePicture";
import Image from "next/image";
// import Link from "next/link";
import {
  Navbar,
  NavbarBrand,
  Link,
} from "@nextui-org/react";
import { useState } from "react";

import { api } from "~/utils/api";

export default function NavigationBar() {

  const user = api.users.getLoggedInUser.useQuery();

  const navPages = [
    { page: "Teams", comingSoon: false },
    { page: "Play", comingSoon: false },
    { page: "Matches", comingSoon: true },
  ];


  const pathname = usePathname();
  return (
    <Navbar
      className="h-50 flex w-full flex-row place-content-between items-center border-b-2 border-zinc-500 border-opacity-75 p-5"
    >


      <NavbarBrand className="hidden md:block">
        <Link href="/play">
          <Image
            className="hover:cursor-pointer"
            width={200}
            unoptimized={true}
            height={200}
            src={"/Roboverse_Animation.gif"}
            alt="VESL Logo"
          ></Image>
        </Link>
      </NavbarBrand>
      <div className="mx-auto w-[50%] px-5">
        <ul className="hidden flex-row place-content-between md:flex">
          {navPages.map((page) => {
            const pageIndex = navPages.indexOf(page);
            const isFirstOrLast =
              pageIndex == 0 || pageIndex == navPages.length - 1;
            return (
              <li className={isFirstOrLast ? "" : "mx-10"} key={pageIndex}>
                <Navbutton
                  selected={pathname == "/" + page.page.toLowerCase()}
                  page={page.page}
                  comingSoon={page.comingSoon}
                ></Navbutton>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

#### Layout Code

```
import React, { type ReactNode } from "react";
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import Image from "next/image";
import NavigationBar from "./NavigationBar";
import VeslVerseTab from "./VeslVerseTab";

const Layout = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const { data: sessionData } = useSession();

  return (
    <>
      <VeslVerseTab />
      {sessionData ? <NavigationBar /> : <Authenticate />}

      {sessionData ? children : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

#### _app.tsx Code where Layout is being applied

```
import { type Session } from "next-auth";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { type AppType } from "next/app";
import { api } from "~/utils/api";
import "~/styles/globals.css";
import Layout from "./components/Layout";
import { Analytics } from "@vercel/analytics/react";
import { NextUIProvider } from "@nextui-org/react";

const MyApp: AppType<{ session: Session | null }> = ({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) => {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <NextUIProvider>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
          <Analytics />
        </Layout>
      </NextUIProvider>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
};
```

I've checked the following things:

- Made sure that where the Layout component is nested in `_app.tsx` wasn't affecting it but maybe that is actually issue, not sure.
- Hardcoded `position="sticky"` on the Navbar Component

Honestly, I'm not sure what is going on and need help figuring this out before I lose my mind.

**EDITS:**

- I defined a height for the Navbar component using h-[100px] and confirmed that style was being applied and the position is set to sticky
  [image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Navbar component is not sticking to the top could be because its parent container doesn't have a defined height.

To make the sticky positioning work, the parent container of the Navbar should have a height specified.

To fix this issue, to use `h-screen` class like this :

```
<Navbar className="h-screen flex w-full flex-row place-content-between items-center border-b-2 border-zinc-500 border-opacity-75 p-5">
```

If it doesn't work, there might be some conflicting styles to other elements on the page.

Let me know more details about your situation.

Comment: I took your suggestion and used h-[100px] to ensure the parent container (Navbar) has a defined height. It didn't fix my issue, but I can confirm that the styles were applied and that the position prop is set to sticky. I have edited my question to include this.

Comment: Your suggestion reminded me that the person who made this project previously had issues with their global styling for the body element. So I went back and set a height for this to 100%, and it fixed my issue. Thank you! Even if your suggestion didn't work, it still got me to where I needed to be :)

Answer (score 0):

The body element being used in the HTML didn't have a set height. I set its height to 100% in the global stylesheet, which fixed my issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had also encountered the same error. This is due to tailwind configuration issues for nextui.

```
 content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}', // Note the addition of the `app` directory.
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    "./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"

 
    // Or if using `src` directory:
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
```

Make sure that the line for ./node_modules is also present within the content. This was the issue with my code as to when I switched to NextUI. You can refer to this in [NextUI docs](https://nextui.org/docs/frameworks/nextjs#tailwind-css-setup) as well. Hope this helps.